# Problems with left outer joins

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm pretty sure that I need to be doing left outer joins on my tables, but i'm not sure if that is 100% true or the syntax to write them in mySQL.

I have this query written:

```
select m.mechanic_id, 
   m.mechanic_name, 
   m.city, 
   m.state, 
   count(mr.mechanic_id) as num_ratings, 
   round(avg(mr.quality_id),2) quality_rating
   round(avg(mr.friendly_id),2) friendly_rating,
   round(avg(mr.professional_id),2) professional_rating
from mechanic m, mechanic_rating mr, rating r
where m.mechanic_id in (1)
and m.mechanic_id = mr.mechanic_id
and mr.quality_id = r.rating_id(+) <-- these cause issues
and mr.friendly_id = r.rating_id(+) <-- these cause issues
and mr.professional_id = r.rating_id(+) <-- these cause issues
group by mechanic_id
```

The (+) are one way to do outer joins in oracle and i'm not sure how to manually write out the outer joins in this query. I'm not even sure if I have them on the right columns.

My table structure looks like this

Mechanic Table

```
|mechanic_id|mechanic_name|city|state|zip|
|PK         |
```

Rating Table

```
|rating_id|rating  |
|1        |terrible|
|2        |bad     |
etc.
```

Mechanic_Rating table

```
|mechanic_rating_id|mechanic_id|quality_id|friendly_id|professional_id|
|unique auto inc   |FK         |
```

The quality_id, friendly_id, and professional_id should all be foreign keys to the rating_id in the rating table.

If i take off (+) from my query, i get zero results so i'm thinking that the problem is that i need to do left outer joins. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn and use the ANSI-92 Standard syntax for doing Join predicates. Using ANSI-92, your query would be written as

```
 select m.mechanic_id,  m.mechanic_name, m.city,
     m.state, count(mr.mechanic_id) num_ratings, 
     round(avg(mr.quality_id),2) quality_rating   
     round(avg(mr.friendly_id),2) friendly_rating,   
     round(avg(mr.professional_id),2) professional_rating
from mechanic m
   Left Join mechanic_rating mr
       On mr.mechanic_id = m.mechanic_id
   Left Join rating r 
       On r.rating_id = mr.quality_id
           And r.rating_id = mr.friendly_id
           And r.rating_id = mr.friendly_id 
 where m.mechanic_id in (1)
 group by mechanic_id
```

NOTE: What does the (1) refer to ?? Are you trying to restrict this to
      where m.mechanic_id = 1  ?

Comment: I am using a variable in my app that contains 1 or more id's. I just used "1" for testing my query.

Comment: I assume this variable is a table variable ??   Otherwise, you do not need to be doing a Group By ...

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue with the (+); using the LEFT OUTER JOIN means that everything from the left table will be included even if there is not an element in the right table.  Likewise the columns for everything on the right (if there was no match) will be NULL.

```
select m.mechanic_id, 
   m.mechanic_name, 
   m.city, 
   m.state, 
   count(mr.mechanic_id) as num_ratings, 
   round(avg(mr.quality_id),2) quality_rating
   round(avg(mr.friendly_id),2) friendly_rating,
   round(avg(mr.professional_id),2) professional_rating
FROM mechanic m LEFT OUTER JOIN mechanic_rating mr ON(m.mechanic_id = mr.mechanic_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating r ON(mr.quality_id = r.rating_id AND 
mr.friendly_id = r.rating_id AND mr.professional_id = r.rating_id) 
WHERE m.mechanic_id in (1) GROUP BY mechanic_id
```

Comment: I think you're confusing `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: The results of both of your queries are the same. Isn't the outer implied?

Comment: If I'm not wrong (and I might be), I thought `LEFT JOIN` was what you're describing above, and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is only those from the left table that don't have a match.

Comment: LEFT JOIN = LEFT OUTTER JOIN; the OUTTER is implied if LEFT is specified.  Likewise, JOIN = INNER JOIN if LEFT is NOT specified.

Answer (score 1):

Your ratings are independent and orthogonal, right?  You need to have the same rating table used in different aliases:

```
from mechanic m
   Left Join mechanic_rating mr
       On mr.mechanic_id = m.mechanic_id
   Left Join rating r_quality
       On r_quality.rating_id = mr.quality_id
   Left Join rating r_friendly
       On r_friendly.rating_id = mr.friendly_id
   Left Join rating r_professional
       On r_professional.rating_id = mr.professional_id
```

Combining them all as you have done is going to simply filter out all rows where the independent ratings aren't all identical, which is probably another thing affecting the results you are seeing.

Although it's the same table for the foreign key, each of the keys is independent and so you need "roles" for the table to act in.

However, because you don't use any rating columns in your select list, you can actually leave them out entirely:

```
select m.mechanic_id, 
   m.mechanic_name, 
   m.city, 
   m.state, 
   count(mr.mechanic_id) as num_ratings, 
   round(avg(mr.quality_id),2) quality_rating
   round(avg(mr.friendly_id),2) friendly_rating,
   round(avg(mr.professional_id),2) professional_rating
from mechanic m, mechanic_rating mr
where m.mechanic_id in (1)
and m.mechanic_id = mr.mechanic_id
group by mechanic_id
```

Note that you can also fix your old style joins:

```
from mechanic m, mechanic_rating mr, rating r_quality, rating r_friendly, rating r_professional
where m.mechanic_id in (1)
and m.mechanic_id = mr.mechanic_id
and mr.quality_id = r_quality.rating_id(+)
and mr.friendly_id = r_friendly.rating_id(+)
and mr.professional_id = r_professional.rating_id(+)
group by mechanic_id
```